# When javers schema changes, are the records I have persisted?

Tags: sql-server, javers

I was wondering, when javers releases a new version that requires database changes, do they handle the database upgrade without losing data or will the tables need to start from an empty state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javers takes care about database schema migration, users' data are safe.
Deleting users' data would be really stupid